# tracking maximum value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to produce a column `B` in a dataframe that tracks the maximum value reached in column `A` since row Index 0.

```
          A     B
 Index    
   0      1     1
   1      2     2
   2      3     3
   3      2     3
   4      1     3
   5      3     3
   6      4     4
   7      2     4
```

I want to avoid iterating, so is there a vectorized solution and if so how could it look like ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html#pandas.Series.cummax):

```
In [257]:
df['B'] = df['A'].cummax()
df

Out[257]:
       A  B
Index      
0      1  1
1      2  2
2      3  3
3      2  3
4      1  3
5      3  3
6      4  4
7      2  4
```